# how to display formatted text but have the actual text

Tags: .net, winforms, text, formatting, textbox

I have my own textbox which inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
I am trying to display texts like 5000000 formatted ==>  5,000,000
but the problem is that Control.Text should return 5000000 but it should display 5,000,000.

I know it is WTF, but i really need it and i couldn't Google a lot because my native language is not English(and anyone can get it from my grammar and Im sorry for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to retrieve it, convert the displayed string to an integer using `int.Parse` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` then convert it back to a string using `ToString` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Neither have I, try it, but how else would you know the two values are equivalent - there has to be some conversion somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag property, as [Andrey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540418/16567), and update the value of the tag property in the `TextChange` event.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: haven't got time to look up the right method names, but hopefully I'm close enough to make sense...)

Create a custom control that derives from `TextBox`.

Add handlers to the control for focus events (or better, override the methods for `OnFocus`/`OnBlur`).  When the control loses focus, store the current text in a private variable (say, `OriginalText`) and update the actual text to your formatted version.  When the control *gets* focus, reinstate the original text.

Comment: +1 for OnBlur(i didn't know about that),but i have already done other things before but the problem was "how to show it?".

Answer (score 0):

use Tag property that every control has

Comment: @Andrey:unfortunately the text is not readonly, and the user should fill it.

Comment: I will try to do it if other people don't send better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep origianl value in the `Tag` property (object).